# Как взять часть сайта в iframe?

Tags: php, html, css, iframe

Как взять часть сайта в *iframe*? Нужно отображать только середку сайт  в *inframe*. Пожалуйста, расскажите подробно, как можно это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Никак. + ко всему в HTML нет такого понятия как "середка", то что на глаз определяется где то в середине - в коде может быть совсем по-другому.